# Title only changing only after i reopen tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a point of sale program and the settings button changes the title of the program. I am storing the title names in a text file "Titlefile.txt" so that it remembers the title next time it opens. The problem I am facing is that when I save title from user input it saves in file but doesn't change the title on the spot. It changes the the title only when I reopen the problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from Globalvariables import *
    
    
    root = Tk() #mainprogram
     
    root.iconbitmap('D:/Gatlabs logo.ico')
    
    #***********************************************************************************
    #SETTINGS MENU
    
    #Mart Name
    #user accounts
    
    root.title("Gatlabs")
    
    def settingsmain():
     global entryformartname, settingmenu
     settingmenu = Toplevel()
     settingmenu.iconbitmap('D:/Gatlabs logo.ico')
     
    
     labelformartname = Label(settingmenu, text = "Enter name of your store")
     entryformartname = Entry(settingmenu)
     entryformartname.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    
     setmartname = Button(settingmenu, text = "setname", command = setname)
     setmartname.grid(row= 0, column = 1)
    
    
     settingmenu.mainloop()
    
    
    
    def setname():
     global Tname,entryformartname
    
     with open('Titlefile.txt','a') as Tfile:
    
         Tfile.write(entryformartname.get() + "\n")
    
    
    opensettingsmenu = Button(root, text= "Open Settings", command = settingsmain)
    
    
    
    
    
    opensettingsmenu.grid(row= 0, column= 0)
    
    
    #**********************************************************************
 
    enter_button = Button( root , text = "ENTER", padx = 20, pady = 10, command= EnterEvent)
    

    enter_button.grid(row= 0, column= 1)

    
    
    try:
     with open('Titlefile.txt','r') as Tfile:
        global Tname
        nme = Tfile.readlines()
        Tname = nme[-1]
        root.title(Tname)
    
    
    except Exception as e:
        with open('Titlefile.txt','w') as Tfile:
         Tfile.write("Mart" + "\n")
            
         
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You do not change the title when you save the file. You only change the title on startup, when you read from the file, so change your save method to something like this:

```
 def setname():
     global Tname,entryformartname
     root.title(entryformartname.get())

     with open('Titlefile.txt','a') as Tfile:
         Tfile.write(entryformartname.get() + "\n")
```